# Merging pdf pages with vector layers in the backend

Tags: openlayers, .net, pdf

I've setup an openlayers instance on a webpage which can load static images. These images are actually the pages of a PDF you can upload. There is a pagination option on it so users can navigate between pages and draw ( using openlayers draw ) on each page individually.

So far so good. I save each page vector layer as GEOJson and send the data back to the back-end. Keep in mind at this point I have both the original PDF and an array of GEOJson (one json for each page ).

At the moment I'm merging the two in the UI by using

> canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);

and posting the base64 string for all pages back to the server to be loaded into memory and saved as PDF. But this way has a lot of downsides like, losing original document quality, a lot of OutOfMemoryExeptions, and it's super slow.

How can i merge the PDF file with the corresponding vector layer in the back-end?

This is an example of what I'm talking about :

[image: Pdf page with polygon drawings]

Comment: The out of memory exceptions and the super-slowness sound, in part, like they may be server resource issues.

Comment: Even so, my project requires 'excluding' some of the features in the backend which will need to trigger a re-generation of the pdf with he new FeatureCollection and doing that right now means i need to reload the pdf pages into a canvas and save them again which is pretty much client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually figured out a way to make this happen in the back-end following these steps.

1. The image loaded in the canvas must have the extent set to the exact size of the original image basically [0,0,width,height].
2. Pdf needs to be re-created page by page using the original width/height of each page using xImage to load the entire page. Mediabox and Rect needs to be set to the correct width and height as well - same size as the original image. All of this is done to ensure drawing is accurately displayed on the page.
3. Using [AddPoly](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/doc/1-methods/addpoly.htm) from ABCPdf, add each of your individual polygons from the submitted feature collection.

Observations:

Drawings would be added as a layer on top of the existing ones so document quality will not be affected.
It will not use a huge amount of memory or cpu and It's quite fast.